# Can Tortoise SVN work on an FTP server?

Tags: svn, ftp, tortoisesvn

I am working on a project which is based on an FTP user with few more programmers.
I want they should be able to collaborate and be able to manage revisions with
    [1]: http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ "Tortoise SVN"].

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not quite how SVN works. You should look at setting up an SVN repository with someone such as Assembla or Unfuddle and then each person would work from your own local copies on your individual machines. The [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) might help, it may also help you set up your own repository somewhere if you don't want to pay.

Comment: If you have access to the server, you install SVN on the server, then each programmer can connect to the repository and their changes will be merged.  Again, this requires SVN installed on the server.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [netdrive](http://www.netdrive.net/download.html), [here's](http://www.ebswift.com/Wiki/wikka.php?wakka=SubversionFTP) a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I think http (or ssh) is the way to go:

- http://howtoforge.com/debian_subversion_websvn (Debian Linux)
- http://www.visualsvn.com/server/ (Windows)

but if you don't feel like doing it yourself you could probably find a hosting out there:

- http://www.svnhostingcomparison.com/

/Johan

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use SSH (putty)?

Nowadays, most hosting companies offer this service. I´ve combined Tortoise on my machine and a remote Subversion client in the server and works perfect!